# What is the license terms for Power BI reports for streaming data

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, licensing, media-streaming, powerbi

Is the Power BI license calculated by report render , I read https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/?b=1 but i am confused ?

Could you tell me what's mean

- 10K rows per hour streaming data
- Daily scheduled data refresh
- 1GB per user data capacity

For SharePoint Online Can I use Power BI free ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Power BI service For Individuals**
*Cost: Free*

1. Connect to cloud sources
2. Simple dashboard sharing
3. 1GB per user data capacity
4. Daily scheduled data refresh
5. 10K rows per hour streaming data

**Power BI Pro service FOR BUSINESSES**
*Cost: $9.99/ user / month*

1. Connect to cloud sources
2. Simple dashboard sharing
3. 10GB per user data capacity
4. Hourly scheduled data refresh
5. 1M rows per hour streaming data
6. Connect to live data sources with full interactivity
7. Collaborate with your team using Office 365 Groups
8. Manage access and sharing through Active Directory
9. Shared data queries through Data Catalog

Comment: What will happen on streaming more than 1M records,

Comment: Will the service return any data?

Comment: No it will not after the limit

Answer (score 0):

The data limit is based on the size of data sent to the Power BI service. If you send a workbook the size of the workbook is counted against your quota. If you send data rows, the size of the uncompressed data rows is counted against your quota. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037558/power-bi-api-limits)

The 10 000 rows/hour limit only applies when you want to refresh dataset in real time by using Azure Stream Analytics or PBI Rest API.
You do not have this limitation when using scheduled refresh. However with the freemium version you can not have more then 5 refresh a day.[Read this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-10-000-rows-limit-Question/m-p/17717#M5099)

Check this link: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/

Comment: thanks for your answer , For SharePoint Online Can I use Power BI free ? , please give me example for 
    10K rows per hour streaming data
    Daily scheduled data refresh
    1GB per user data capacity